# Add columns to a wpf bounded datagrid

Tags: wpf

I have a data grid which is bounded to a simple List.
now i want to add a checkbox column to it that when iterating threw the items of the grid i will be able to add to another list only the rows where the chckbox is selected.

is it possible?

many thanks

Comment: i don't understand "will be able to add to another list"...

Comment: sorry for that, i meant to create a new list with only the items that their row is checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure can. First I would recommend that your List be an ObservableCollection so that the DataGrid stays bound.

#### First Create the DataGrid in XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="SampleDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SampleObservableCollection}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="SampleOne" Binding="{Binding Path=SampleOne}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="SampleTwo" Binding="{Binding Path=SampleTwo}"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SampleThreeCheckBox">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=SampleThreeCheckBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

*(SampleOne, SapleTwo, and SampleThreeCheckBox are all properties in your object that's in your list.)*

#### Second update your Code-Behind

Set the DataContext to this or your ViewModel

```
DataContext = this; // Better if you use a ViewModel
```

Then create a new list with only the check ones and set that to your ItemSource of the new DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a CollectionViewSource and a Filter.  The main binds to the List (or ObservableCollection).   And the second is bound to a  CollectionViewSource and a Filter on the checkbox value.   I like the way ListView GridView presents compared to DataGrid.